# What's wrong with my code? RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python-3.x

Following is the code, when I run solution.shoppingOffers([2,5], [[3,0,5],[1,2,10]], [3,2]), python shows: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison.

```
class Solution(object):
    def shoppingOffers(self, price, special, needs):
    """
    :type price: List[int]
    :type special: List[List[int]]
    :type needs: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
        return self.helper(price, special, needs, 0)

    def helper(self, price, special, needs, index):
        if index == len(special):
            return self.dot_product(price, needs)
        else:
            offer = special[index]
            flag = False
            for index, value in enumerate(needs):
                if value < offer[index]:
                    flag = True
                    break
            if flag:
                return self.helper(price, special, needs, index + 1)
            else:
                return min(self.helper(price, special, needs, index + 1), offer[-1] + self.helper(price, special, self.minus(needs, offer), index))

    def dot_product(self, prices, needs):
        return sum(i[0] * i[1] for i in zip(prices, needs))

    def minus(self, needs, offer):
        return [i[0] - i[1] for i in zip(needs, offer)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the background of the programm but is it correct that you want to overwrite the index variable in the for loop?

```
for index, value in enumerate(needs):
    if value < offer[index]:
        flag = True
        break
```

That way the recursion might go on infinitely since

```
if index == len(special):
    return self.dot_product(price, needs)
```

never holds True. In that case changing the variable name might fix the problem.